# Counting the possible spot in matrixe such that filled by to such conditions

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Problem:
filling $(2n+1)\cdot(2n+1)$ matrix with integers from $1$ to $(2n+1)^2$

1. each row be an increase sequence from left to right
2. each column be an increase sequence from top to bottom

Count the number of spot that $(2n^2+2n+1)$ can fit in.

I guess it is about catalan number but I have no clue. I’d try to find a bijection between matrix and $(2n+1)\cdot (2n+1)$ path but im not sure

Comment: [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011533/ways-to-fill-integer-matrix-with-increasing-rows-and-columns) may help.

Comment: I think under $1$ you mean "each row"?

Comment: The text and title of the question don't correspond. The title seems to imply that you want to count all ways of filling the matrix under these conditions, whereas the text seems to imply that you only want to count the slots in the matrix that the number $2n^2+2n+1$ can be in in one of these filled matrices. Which one is it?

Comment: my mistake. the second one was a exact question